# why in node.js fs module removing files is named "unlink"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js fs module remove files is unlink or unlinkSync. Why it is named unlink? Does it have some origin from somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unlink` is a very common convention for this action. See the [linux manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html), the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Deleting-Files.html#:%7E:text=The%20unlink%20function%20deletes%20the,in%20the%20header%20file%20unistd.), and [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) for examples.

From [a discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/90wr98/why_is_file_deletion_called_unlink_instead_of/) on this subject:

> Deletion is a kind of unlinking. It just removes the pointer/link to the file from the system tables. It doesn't physically go and clean the bits.

> You can have multiple links to the same file. The file is only deleted when the ref count reaches zero. So technically its unlinking.

Answer (score 1):

Files paths are represented with links and files are accessed with their links. So when you remove a file you no longer have a link to access. You unlink it.